# Align two elements of different height in the middle of a div

Tags: html, css

I have two elements [a custom button and a paragraph line]in my fixed footer (always stays on page) that I've been trying to horizontally align in the center.

```
        <div class="footer">

                <div class="co_footer_content">

                        <button class="func_button" >
                            <span class="func_button_ico"></span>
                        </button>

                        <p class="footer_txt">Small one liner {{varContent}}</p>

                </div>
        </div>
```

Here's the CSS

```
.footer{
  height: 87px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.func_button{
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    height: 44px;
    width: 44px;
    margin: auto;
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.func_button_ico{
    background:url(./assets/func_button.png) no-repeat top left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    height: 44px;
    width: 44px;
    float: right;
}

.footer_txt{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
}
```

As seen in the above html snippet, there is `varConent` which changes the width of my content to some extent. So everytime the content changes, the `<p>` recenters. The height is fixed however i.e. the content doesn't go to more than one line.

I want the custom button to stick with this variable width `<p>` so that they are in the same line but also to be able adjust the button's position independent of `<p>` What would be the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/johnsackson/pen/ZobMLj

```
  <div class="co_footer_content">

    <button class="func_button">
        <span class="func_button_ico"></span>
    </button>

    <p class="footer_txt">Small one liner {{varContent}}</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.footer{
  height: 87px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.co_footer_content {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.func_button{
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    height: 44px;
    width: 44px;
    margin: auto;
    display:block;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.func_button_ico{
    background:url(./assets/func_button.png) no-repeat top left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    height: 44px;
    width: 44px;
}

.footer_txt{
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: It seems like I can't still can't completely adjust the positions of those elements separately. I want the button to be positioned to be just a little bit below the text itself. But as soon I try to move the button, the text moves along as well.

Comment: Try changing '.footer_txt' style's 'vertical-align' property's value as 'top' or 'bottom' and let me know if this is what you are looking for

Comment: In your codepen for example, if I add `margin-top: 40px` to `footer_txt`, it doesn't seem to change the text's position [ https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vjNVNZ ] Just to get pixel position over those elements separately.

Comment: if you want to change based on margin-top value then change the '.footer_text' paragraph's 'display' property's value as 'inline-block' . https://codepen.io/johnsackson/pen/PePyzR